# Check past month or not PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I'd be happy to help code that does not really work
I want to see if the project was published last month or not.
If yes then get a positive result.

```
    //$project_time="2012-08-01 13:43:49";
    $project_time="2012-10-02 14:05:09";
 $end=mktime(0,0,0,date("m",strtotime($project_time))+1,date("d",strtotime($project_time)),d    ate("y",strtotime($project_time)));
 $end=date("d.m.y",$end);
 $today=mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));
 $today=date("d.m.y",$today);    

echo 'Project date '.$date.'<br />';
echo 'End date '.$end.'<br />';
echo 'Today '.$today.'<br />';

if($today<$end){
  echo " open<br />";
}
else{
  echo " finish<br />";
}
```

PROJECT_TIME first gives a good result and the other not.
  $ end create date based on $ PROJECT_TIME plus one month.
Variable data TOTDAY get today's date.
And the comparison I want to get an answer whether past month from PROJECTTIME

If someone has understood and can help I would be happy.

Comment: if($today<$end){ - don't compare your dates as strings... compare them as timestamps

Comment: PROJECT_TIME listed in a database as timestamp. Now I need to check if a month after it is registered.

Comment: apart from your question, can't you use strtotime( $project_time ); to get $end timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime is the function you want to use. Simply use the following syntax:

```
$end = date('d.m.y', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($project_time));
```

*EDIT*

What people are saying about comparing strings is correct. Don't compare strings, compare the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting it to something like:

```
$project_time = "2012-10-02 14:05:09";
$project_endtimestamp = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($project_time));

echo 'Project date ' . $date . '<br />';
echo 'End date ' . date('d.m.y', $project_endtimestamp) . '<br />';
echo 'Today ' . date('d.m.y') . '<br />';

if (time() < $project_endtimestamp) {
    echo " open<br />";
} else {
    echo " finish<br />";
}
```

**EDIT:** Didn't completely understood the question. Added `+1 month` in `strtotime` call as per @Simon Germain answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem: You're comparing two "d.m.y" strings.

This will always fail, because PHP sees them as plain text, not as dates. Therefore, asking which one is bigger will generally give the wrong answer.

Also: Get rid of all that crazyness with the old-style date handling functions. PHP has much better ways to do that sort of thing these days.

```
$project_time="2012-10-02 14:05:09";

$projDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $project_time);
$dateNow = new DateTime();
if($projDate < $dateNow) {
    ... do something here...
}
```